# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable but every variables defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, slack-api

I am trying to build a bot that connects to slack, and keep receiving a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "happybotV4.2.py", line 217, in <module>
    av_mood, user_count, total_mood = datamood(user_answer, user_id, user_count, total_mood, av_mood)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the code:

```
if slackinput_list and len(slackinput_list) > 0:
  user_answer, user_id, channel, event_type = parse_slack_useranswer(slackinput_list)
  #print(user_answer,user_id)#test
  if user_answer and user_id and user_id != 'U7GRT34H3' and event_type=="message":
    if user_answer=="1" or user_answer=="5":
      print(user_answer, user_id, user_count, total_mood, av_mood) #test
      #if user_id not in user_list:
      av_mood, user_count, total_mood = datamood(user_answer, user_id, user_count, total_mood, av_mood)
```

And datamood's code:

```
def datamood(mood, user, count, total_mood, average_mood):
  print(user_list)
  if user not in user_list:
    count = count+1
    mood_user.append(mood)
    user_list.append(user)
    print(user_list, user)
    if len(mood_user)>0:
      for i in mood_user :
        if i=="1":
          n=1
        elif i=="5":
          n=5

        total_mood = total_mood + n
        print(total_mood)#test
      average_mood = total_mood/count
      print (average_mood, count) #test
      return average_mood, count, total_mood
    else:
      return average_mood, count, total_mood
```

In fact datamood works one time, but when I try to call it a second time I get the error. I checked that every variable (that is `user_answer`, `user_id`, `user_count`, `total_mood`, `av_mood`) are not None and are in the correct format.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to post the code for `datamood()`. Apparently, it sometimes returns None.

Comment: If one of the variables is not defined, you would get a `NameError`, not a `TypeError`.

Comment: Here is the code: 
:code:
def datamood(mood, user, count, total_mood, average_mood):
    print(user_list)
    if user not in user_list:
        count = count+1
        mood_user.append(mood)
        user_list.append(user)
        if len(mood_user)>0:
            for i in mood_user :
                if i=="1":
                    n=1
                elif i=="5":
                    n=5
                total_mood = total_mood + n
            average_mood = total_mood/count
            return average_mood, count, total_mood

Comment: Most likely one of the variables that you are passing into `datamood()` either contain a `NoneType` object or your method is returning a `NoneType` object, in otherwords, no value associated with the variable. Without more information, we can't really do anything. Please considering including a [MCVE] for us to work with, or posting more of your code. You can use the traceback to determine associated code, and you can use print statements to test if variables contain value before calling the `datamood()` method and after it returns values.

Comment: @ArthurDuchet-Suchaux please edit your original question and include the code.

Comment: Please post code for review.  My guess is scoping on a variable is nullifying the value but impossible to determine without the code behind it.  Thx.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I just updated my post

Comment: thanks @artomason it worked!

Comment: @ArthurDuchet-Suchaux I have posted an answer. If it has helped solve your issue, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to the `datamood()` method is expecting a value to be returned. Since your logic does not explicitly tell your method what to do when a `user` exists in `user_list` the method returns `None` or a `NoneType` object. When a return is not explicitly set in a Python method, it will always return `None`. Hence, when you first call the method and the `user` does not exist, the return value is expected; however, when you call the method and `user` does exist, your method returns `None`.